# ReportBuilder embedded FormatDateTime errors in switch comparator

Tags: datetime, expression, reportbuilder3.0

I have a datetime field that may be blank. when it is not blank I want to show only the date portion. I used:

`=FormatDateTime(Fields!myDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)`

This works except for blank entries which are replaced by "1/1/0001".

I used a switch statement but it returns an error when the condition is met. The switch statement is:

`=switch(Fields!myDate.Value<>"", FormatDateTime(Fields!myDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate))`

This works for the blanks but yields an error for datetime entries.

The workaround is to change the stored procedure to return only the date for the datetime field. I would prefer to have the time value in case it is needed in the future.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or if there is a report builder solution that works.

Comment: Tried with IIF and same error result:

Comment: I believe the parser doesn't support nested operations for functions/members.  Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IIF(Fields!myDate.Value Is Nothing, "", Format(Fields!myDate.Value, 
"dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Please mark as duplicate. This is a duplicate answer of my similar question (with Answer by Jeffrey Van Laethem) "SSRS expression fails for IIF date with #error"